# Serial Port in Delphi 7 with ComPort do not send the data fully

Tags: delphi, tcomport

I have a problem with accessing my serial port in Delphi when using the `TComPort` component. It can not send the data fully, but some data is lost randomly, like this example:

> 061:1268:-108:16596:-462:239:-75:0.000000:0.000000
>   061:
>   061:1240:-84:16616:-425:235:-54:0.000000:0.
>   061:1220:-96:16620:-418:224:-69:0.000000:0.000000:0.0055
>   061:1220:-72:16676:-420:246:-72:0.0
>   061:1100:-176:16688:-460:224:-45:0.000000:0.000000:0.0056
>   061:1164:-144:16676:-442:23
>   061:1272:-136:16456:-413:219:-84:0.000000:0.000000:0.0056
>   061:1096:-152:16616
>   061:1096:-140:16656:-427:235:-88:0.000000:0.000000:0.0056
>   061:1200:-1
>   061:1192:-84:16664:-447:228:-60:0.000000:0.000000:0.0055
>   061
>   061:1208:-116:16576:-421:233:-56:0.000000:0.000000
>   061:1208:-128:16584:-427:226:-94:0.000000:0.000000:0.0056
>   061:1172:-264:16560:-436:257:-72:0.000000:
>   061:1196:-200:16724:-428:234:-78:0.000000:0.000000:0.0056

The right data should contain 10 values, like below:

> 061:1196:-200:16724:-428:234:-78:0.000000:0.000000:0.0056

Please help me solve this problem. I'm a beginner in Delphi.

This is my code:

```
procedure TForm1.ComDataPacket1Packet(Sender: TObject; const Str: String);
begin
  allData := allData + Str;
  if Pos (#$A, allData) > 0 then
  begin
    awal := 1;
    batas := Pos(':', allData);
    Delete(allData, awal, batas);

    //Data Gyroscope
    awal := 1;
    batas := Pos(':', allData);
    gyroX := Copy(allData, awal, batas-1);
    Delete(allData, awal, batas);
    Label2.Caption := gyroX;

    awal := 1;
    batas := Pos(':', allData);
    gyroY := Copy(allData, awal, batas-1);
    Delete(allData, awal, batas);
    Label3.Caption := gyroY;

    awal := 1;
    batas := Pos(':', allData);
    gyroZ := Copy(allData, awal, batas-1);
    Delete(allData, awal, batas);
    Label4.Caption := gyroZ;

    //Data Accelero
    awal := 1;
    batas := Pos(':', allData);
    accX := Copy(allData, awal, batas-1);
    Delete(allData, awal, batas);
    Label6.Caption := accX;

    awal := 1;
    batas := Pos(':', allData);
    accY := Copy(allData, awal, batas-1);
    Delete(allData, awal, batas);
    Label7.Caption := accY;

    awal := 1;
    batas := Pos(':', allData);
    accZ := Copy(allData, awal, batas-1);
    Delete(allData, 1, batas);
    Label8.Caption := accZ;

    //Data GPS
    awal := 1;
    batas := Pos(':', allData);
    Lat := Copy(allData, awal, batas-1);
    Delete(allData, awal, batas);
    Label10.Caption := Lat;

    awal := 1;
    batas := Pos(':', allData);
    Long := Copy(allData, awal, batas-1);
    Delete(allData, awal, batas);
    Label11.Caption := Long;

    awal := 1;
    palingAkhir := Pos(#$A, allData);
    Alt := Copy(allData, awal, palingAkhir-1);
    Delete(allData, awal, palingAkhir);
    Label12.Caption := Alt;

    //Showing to Memo
    Memo1.Text := Memo1.Text + Str + #$D;
    SendMessage(Memo1.Handle, EM_LINESCROLL, 0, Memo1.Lines.Count);
  end
```

Comment: We can't help you with this code taken out of context. Either ask a better question (see articles at the [help]) or do some debugging.

Comment: You are using packet exchange approach, when library provides data packet integrity, if markers/sentinels are set properly. But why do you check for markers again `if (Pos (#$A, allData)>0) `? Log all data without treatment and check whether some bytes are lost or not.

Comment: I assume that your list of data is taken from Memo1, in which case the problem is that data is missing from Str - i.e. the problem is somewhere else. There is no point in showing this code when it clearly does not contain your problem.

Comment: Most probable cause is a mismatch in parameters for the serial comms between sender and receiver, or, if the sender is hardware, something like inaccurate clock for sending data, etc.

Comment: There is no "standard" ComPort library for Delphi. There are a lot of them. So please state exactly which one you are using and show the code related to serial communication instead of the code consuming data which is irrelevent. Serial communication is a hard topic. It is easy to looze data, especially if the component you use is not interrupt driven/multithreaded and you don't make use of hardware handshaking.

Comment: @fpiette I'm using ComPort Library version 4.10. Exactly, I need to breakdown those data to get the value of some unit from my device which consist of accelerometer and gyroscope from GY-521 module; the value of latitude, longitude, and altitude from GPS (SKM53). Both module is  connected to arduino pro mini. I'm sorry sir, I do not got which the code do you mean, the code that I write in delphi or in arduino IDE?

Comment: @MBo, I check the new line #$A, because my data do not feed the new line

Comment: @Arin Siska Sorry, I don't catch logic of this phrase. You may check $A if device sends it as marker of the end of data packet.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see how packet mode helps you. Try an approach without packets, make OnRXChar event handler. I assume that your data contains end marker byte $A, no start marker.

```
var
  Accumulator: AnsiString;
  List: TStringList;
...
//OnCreate
List:= TStringList.Create;
List.Delimiter := ':';

//OnDestroy
 List.Free;


procedure XXX.RXChar(Sender: TObject; Count: Integer);
var
  s, DataStr: AnsiString;
  APos: Integer;
begin
  ComPort.ReadStr(s, Count);
  Accumulator := Accumulator + s;
  APos := Pos (#$A, Accumulator);
  if APos > 0 then begin
    DataStr := Copy(Accumulator, 1, APos - 1);
    Delete(Accumulator, 1, APos);
    Memo1.Lines.Add(DataStr);
    List.DelimitedText := DataStr;
    if List.Count = 10 then
      TreatListItems; //extract data from List[]
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Thank you for the alternative, I'll try it